# Disadvantages of including devModeRedirectEnabled=true in production?

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I've run GWT 2.6.1 SuperDevMode successfully today, and I'm wondering if we could just leave this line in the .gwt.xml file:

```xml
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
```

In this artical (http://blog.ltgt.net/how-does-gwts-super-dev-mode-work/), it suggests to remove it for production. I'd like to know why?

Any performance or security impacts if we keep that for production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's now *on* by default starting with GWT 2.6.0, because security measures have been added.

From the [release notes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html):

> **Release Notes for 2.6.0 (RC4)**
>
> This release enabled the Super Dev Mode hook by default

[…]

> **Super Dev Mode**
>
> - Security: with 2.6 we believe it's safe to turn on the Super Dev Mode hook and leave it on in production. As an extra precaution, we recommend setting the devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp configuration property to ensure that it can only load JavaScript from localhost and your developers' machines in your own domain.
> - Security: automatically disable Super Dev Mode on https pages (Another precaution, and it doesn't work anyway due to mixed-content restrictions.)

(note: `devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp` defaults to only allowing `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like we can just leave it there, which would save some time.

Comment: …or you could just remove it, given that you're setting it to its default value ;-)

Answer (score 3):

However, since Super Dev Mode is still an experimental feature, the redirect is not enabled by default. To enable Super Dev Mode for a GWT application, you must currently add the following lines to its module.xml file:

```
 <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
 <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
```

(Currently, only the xsiframe linker supports Super Dev Mode.)

---

### However, there are also some disadvantages you should be aware of:

- Work to secure Super Dev Mode is incomplete. In the meantime, we recommend only running the code server on localhost or behind a firewall. *Also, as a safety measure, Super Dev Mode should be disabled in **production** apps*. (That is, set devModeRedirectEnabled to false.)
- We expect that Super Dev Mode will be able to support any modern browser, but for now, we have only tested it on Chrome and Firefox.
  Currently, Super Dev Mode doesn't work on some very large GWT apps where classic Dev Mode works.
- Only one GWT linker supports Super Dev Mode
- Currently, only the Chrome debugger supports Source Maps. We hope browser support will improve so that you can easily debug problems that only happen in other browsers, but in the meantime, you'll have to resort to other debugging tricks, such as adding logging statements and recompiling.
- Many features of Java debuggers aren't available when using Super Dev Mode. For example, when inspecting variables in the Chrome debugger, the field names and values are JavaScript, not Java.
- Currently, Super Dev Mode doesn't support running Java web apps (war files) like classic Dev Mode. The workaround is to run them on a separate server.
- Since Super Dev Mode doesn't run GWT applications in a JVM, some runtime checks don't happen. For example, there won't be any IndexOutOfBoundsException when an array index is out of range.

#### For these reasons, Super Dev Mode is still considered experimental only.

For full description please refer [GWT Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) that is last updated on June 2012.

---

Please have a look at [Running in Production Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideProdMode)

You are referring an article [How does GWT's Super Dev Mode work?](http://blog.ltgt.net/how-does-gwts-super-dev-mode-work/) that is last updated on June 2012.

Comment: That article is almost **2 years old**, things have changed since then, and the _“still”_ in the last phrase is no longer true.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Thanks let me find it out in the latest document.